# Efficiently handling multiple Python TCP sockets simultaneously/alternately

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, network-programming

My setup consists of 8 custom boards (machines), PC, switch and a router, all connected with LAN cables. Each of the machines have their own IP address and act as servers. PC acts as a client and uses Python Socket library to connect to the machines.

PC is operated by the user. The user chooses which machine(s) they want to control at the moment and as a response the following sequence is performed by the PC: *create socket -> connect -> send command to machine -> receive answer from machine -> close socket*. The machines are programmed to answer to a command once and don't send any other data themselves.

For each command and answer pair a new socket is created. It seems like whenever PC wants to connect to another IP address then it takes a long time (9+ seconds) to establish the connection, whereas when creating a socket for the same IP address it takes around 0.0005 seconds.

I wrote a simple test code performing *create socket -> connect -> disconnect* to illustrate my problem.

```
import socket
import select
import time
import numpy as np

class Machine():
    def __init__(self, nr):
        host_address = "192.168.0.7" + str(nr)
        port_nr = 7
        self.server_addr = (host_address, port_nr)

    def open_connection(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.settimeout(1)
        try:
            self.s.connect(self.server_addr)
            return True
        except socket.timeout:
            return False
        except socket.error as e:
            return False

    def send_cmd(self):
        try:
            command = "POS"
            nsent = self.s.send(command.encode('utf-8'))
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            return False

    def receive_data(self):
        try:
            readable_s, _, _ = select.select([self.s], [], [], 0.001)
            if readable_s:
                msg = self.s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if "S,X" in msg and ",E;" in msg:
                    return True
        except Exception as e:
            return False


machines = {nr: Machine(nr) for nr in range(1,10) if nr != 5}
rep = 1000

for nr, machine in machines.items():
    connect_time_lst = []

    for i in range(rep):
        start_time = time.time()

        while True:
            if machine.open_connection():
                machine.s.close()
                end_time = time.time()
                delta_time = end_time - start_time
                connect_time_lst.append(np.round(delta_time, 4))
                break

    av = np.round(np.mean(connect_time_lst),4)
    maxi = np.max(connect_time_lst)
    max_rep = np.argmax(connect_time_lst)
    over_9s =  np.argwhere(np.array(connect_time_lst)>9).flatten()
    mini = np.min(connect_time_lst)
    min_rep = np.argmin(connect_time_lst)

    print("M{}: mean time = {}s, max time = {}s at rep {}, time over 9s at rep(s) {}, min time = {}s at rep {}".format(nr, av, maxi, max_rep, over_9s, mini, min_rep))
```

Output of this program:
[image: Connecting-disconnecting to each machine 1000 times]

The same also happens when pinging the machines from the terminal. It takes 9+ seconds to ping a new IP address and the corresponding packet loss is +50%. When pinging the same IP address again it takes less than 1 second and the packet loss is 0%.

Is there a way to switch quicker between different IP addresses? Or is there a common practice about how long or how many messages the Python socket should be used for?

Previously I have also tried to keep the connections open the whole day. Meaning I create the socket and connect in the morning, send commands and receive answers from different machines during the day, and close sockets for all the machines in the evening. This way I have been able to communicate with different machines without any noticeable delays.

However around once a day 1-3 out of 8 sockets for would timeout from the PC (client) side, while the machine (server) would keep holding on on to the connection. That made it impossible for the PC to connect again until the machine had been restarted. Because it's not possible to restart the machine remotely, I switched to the approach of creating and closing the connection after each data exchange.

Comment: Seems like your machines aren't doing TCP/IP very well. I guess you have no control over them, and you just have to deal with what you've got?

Comment: You can use a tool like Wireshark to diagnose what is going on in those 9 seconds.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a software issue and thus not a python issue, it sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: It is always better to check with simple programme before adding complex functionality, I would advice you to just create a simple client and server programme. Run the client on your machine and server on some other machine on your LAN. Make the server programe in such a way that i will accept a string from the client and will send the the same string as a response. Give print statement to print the time at various points of the programme. This way you will get a better idea. Also check the PING response time.

Comment: The problem was that the machines had different IP addresses, but same MAC addresses. Once this was changed the average time for successful connection-disconnection changed to 0.003 seconds. And the maximum connection time for 1000 repetitions wasn't necessarily during the first repetition.